# RESTful WCF Service: Sending back user confirmation

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

In my Rest WCF project I am saving data to DB.
My question is when the user sends data to my wcf service, 
I need to validate the data and if there is any error 
how can I inform it back to the user?
And once data is successfully saved to Database , I need to
send a confirmation to the user saying "Data successfully saved".
How can I do this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx):

```
WebOperationContext context = WebOperationContext.Current;
context.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

Comment: Hi Erno, thanks for your reply. I am assuming the above solution works for data successfully saved to DB. What if the user enters text in number field how do we to inform the user about that.

Comment: @Henry, you use the the status code to inform about the overall success or failure. To pass back extra information you could define a message structure and return that structure as content of the http response or the return type of the WCF method.